# ember How to address a action handler from a action within a view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How to address an action handler from a action within a view ?

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/yexoko/4/edit?html,js,output)

At the moment I can't reach one of them :( instead I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 's.send')`

**My button in html :**

`{{action 'delete' view.model.customer }}`

**A short draft of the situation:**
[image: Image of my draft]

EDIT:

Route action hash:

```
  actions:{
    delete:function(id){
      console.log(id);
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
```

View action hash:

```
  actions:{
    delete:function(id){
      console.log(id);
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show your code of the actions hash in the controller, route, or view.

Comment: @duncan-walker is right. Need a failing bin to know what is really going on. But maybe this will help {{action 'delete' view.model.customer target=view}}

Comment: Added them but because they are doing nothing just reporting the id I didn't post them from the beginning @blessenm already tried `target=view` also `targetObject=view`